# How to enable folders in Chrome devtools > Sources > Page > top > (no domain) (files with //# sourceURL=...)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to show folders for path's in Chrome devtool > Page panel 
for tree nodes in top > (no domain)

these are node comming from js eval with a //# sourceURL=...

as my code contains a lot of these I want them to show as

```
- top
  - MyDomain
    - MyFile
  - (no domain)
    - FolderA
      - Eval1
      - Eval2
    - FolderB
      - Eval3
      - Eval4
```

Instead of

```
- top
  - MyDomain
    - MyFile
  - (no domain)
    - FolderA/Eval1
    - FolderA/Eval2
    - FolderB/Eval3
    - FolderB/Eval4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Include the domain (origin) in the sourceUrl.

*I had to find this out by trial and error, it is not well-documented anywhere.*

**JS syntax:**

```
//# sourceURL=http://mySite:8000/FolderA/File1.js
```

**Css syntax:**

```
/*# sourceURL=http://mySite:8000/FolderA/File1.css */
```

## Build it in the browser:

**Create a sourceUrl** from a relative url:

```
function jsSrcUrl(path) {
    return "//# sourceURL=" + window.origin + path + " \n";
}

var src = "/js/myScript.js"; // use this url in your GET request via fetch()
var sourceUrl = jsSrcUrl(src); // append this and eval it later
```

**Create a sourceUrl** during a fetch request:

```
var src = "/ui/vue.js";
var fullUrl;

fetch(src)
  .then(function(response) {
    fullUrl = response.url;
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    console.log(text)
  })
var sourceUrl = "//# sourceURL=" + fullUrl + " \n"
```

**Add a sourceUrl to your script (which is a string before eval):**

```
var scriptWithSrcUrl = script.concat(sourceUrl);
```

**Eval your script** to load your script (string) into the browser and sources panel

```
eval(scriptWithSrcUrl)
```

### **Put it all together: Create a sourceUrl during a fetch request AND append it to the script AND eval it:**

```
async function loadScript(url) {
    var fullUrl;

    async function getScript() {
        return fetch(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                fullUrl = response.url;
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(function(text) {
                return text;
            });
    }
    var script = await getScript();
    var sourceUrl = "\n//# sourceURL=" + fullUrl + " \n";
    var scriptWithSrcUrl = script.concat(sourceUrl);
    (1, eval)(scriptWithSrcUrl);
}

loadScript("/path/to/script.js");
```

Look in your devtools sources panel and find your file in the proper folder and domain!

## Dear Google, Mozilla, Microsoft, & Apple:

The fetch api is nice, but fetching js/css/html via a get request, injecting a sourceUrl, and eval'ing it is not just lame, it's ultra lame.  Loading everything in a script tag in the document head doesn't play nice with lazy-loading components, code-splitting, tree shaking, and SSR in general.  **Wouldn't it be *nice*** if there was an api to load **js**, **css**, html **templates**, **components**, and js **modules** into global scope - **all from js** (not from html) natively using browser api's?

A way that doesn't involve:

- ES6 module syntax and scope (for loading into local scope)
- `fetch()` + sourceUrl + `eval()`
- `document.createElement('script')` + set src + `onload()` (pollutes the doc head)
- Some library/dependency (Jquery $.getScript(), Fetch inject, Requirejs, etc.)

I am sure that this api already exists within the browser, script tags probably already consume that js api...can't we just have nice things?

```
loadScript("path/to/js.js"); // for loading js into global scope
```

## Such a simple use case, yet no API.